# Use activerecord to find records that are not in many-to-many relation for specific user (ruby-on-rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, many-to-many

Ok, my database contains three tables: users, words, statuses (it is a relation table and has no ID). Each user CAN have many words and each word CAN be repeated for different users (some users and words can be not associated). Each pair user-word has status (true or false) which is recorded in the status table.

Database:

```
  users            statuses              words
| id   |      | user_id         |      | id   |   
| name |      | word_id         |      | word |
|      |      | status: boolean |      |      |
```

I want to create a web page that will contain all the words that are HAS NO status for the current user.

Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :statuses
  has_many :words, through: :statuses
end

class Status < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :word
  validates :word, uniqueness: {scope: :user}
end

class Word < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

I wrote a request it works fine but it is ugly and I feel that is not right

```
def words_without_status
    sql = "SELECT words.* FROM words
           LEFT  JOIN (SELECT status.* FROM status
           LEFT  JOIN users ON users.id = status.user_id
           WHERE (status.user_id = #{current_user.id})) AS tmp
           ON words.id = tmp.word_id
           WHERE tmp.word_id IS NULL
           ORDER BY id"
    @words = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
end
```

Here's the code that returns all the words with status for a current_user but I need the opposite.

```
@words = current_user.words
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: You do not actually use your `status.status` boolean column anyhow. Assuming that is simply an unnecessary information (so that "*word that HAS NO status*" means *there is actually no record in `status` table*), your initial sql seems fine, but may be we could work out something more elegant.

Pretend you're trying to get the IDs of words which have any status for a particular user first:

```
SELECT status.word_id FROM status WHERE (status.user_id = #{current_user.id})
```

Getting all the words without a status is an opposite operation, so you could do it with:

```
SELECT words.* WHERE words.id NOT IN (
  SELECT status.word_id FROM status WHERE (status.user_id = #{current_user.id})
)
```

In case you prefer an activerecordish approach, it could be written as:

```
@words = Word.where("id NOT IN (SELECT status.word_id FROM status WHERE (status.user_id = :user_id))", user_id: current_user.id)
```

Using `LEFT JOINS` instead of `NOT IN` could be another option, but I ommit this one for you to discover. Actual perfomance difference should be measured for each particular situation separately.

Comment: `status` is not used in the snippets posted above but what if it's set by a background job? What if the results are passed to a function that handles `Word`s differently depending on its status? The claim that `status` can be dropped might be unjustified.

Comment: Thank you, it works great . I also read the answer of Greg Navis and edited your answer . Here's what I got @words = Word.where.not(id: Status.select(:word_id).where(user: current_user))

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below query:
Find words for current_user such that its status is false-

```
@words = current_user.statuses.includes(:words).where("status : false")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches: with a join or a subquery.

The one with a join looks like

```
Word.includes(:statuses => :word).where(statuses: { user: current_user, status: true })
```

If you want to use a subquery then:

```
Word.where(id: Status.select(:word_id).where(status: true, user: current_user))
```

I recommend that you benchmark the two approaches on your data set and choose the faster one.

Comment: `Word.where(id: Status.select)` is not a subquery, it actually makes two queries.

Comment: @twonegatives, this is incorrect. Active Record does support subqueries. In this case it generates `SELECT "words".* FROM "words" WHERE "words"."id" IN (SELECT "statuses"."word_id" FROM "statuses" WHERE "statuses"."status" = 't' AND "statuses"."user_id" = 1)`.

Comment: whoa, seems something new to me. may be the magic is in the `select` method? thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I should not have to add the status column in the question , the final answer is @words = Word.where.not(id: Status.select(:word_id).where(user: current_user))